# Javascript Image Links

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, hyperlink

I have 5 image links that will display another image within that same id when clicked to an active page. So far I got the all images to change to one image, but I want them to revert back to the original image when another image link is clicked. I understand I can do this using HTML and CSS, but I'd like to know how to use JavaScript for this feature.

Here is the HTML:

```
<a href="#" onclick="changeImg(1)"><img src="images/tn_wolverine.jpg" id="imgBox1"></a>
<a href="#" onclick="changeImg(2)"><img src="images/tn_wolverine.jpg" id="imgBox2"></a>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
function changeImg(ID) {
    var obj = document.getElementById("imgBox"+ID).src="images/tn_wolverine2.jpg";

}
```

Comment: take current image src, make it's other's images src and change the current image src to the new src.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a flag to record the index of the lastest clicked image. Use this index to revert the image back to the original picture when user click another image. And then replace the prev index flag with the new one.

I wrote a simple "poker" example: [Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/K5869/1/)

**HTML**

```
<a href="#">
  <img class="poker" src="http://pic1a.nipic.com/2009-03-03/200933143727699_2.jpg"/>
</a>
<a href="#">
  <img class="poker" src="http://pic1a.nipic.com/2009-03-03/200933143727699_2.jpg"/>
</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
(function(){
  var pokers = document.getElementsByClassName("poker"),len=pokers.length,imgs=["http://pica.nipic.com/2007-10-16/20071016115825247_2.jpg","http://img.teapic.com/thumbs/201210/23/141801plfndrdzabzjdaok.jpg.middle.jpg"];
  var defaultImg = "http://pic1a.nipic.com/2009-03-03/200933143727699_2.jpg";
  var prevIndex = -1;

  for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
    pokers[i].addEventListener("click",(function(index){
        return function(){
            //no action if user clicked the same poker
            if(prevIndex===index) return;
            if(prevIndex!==-1)pokers[prevIndex].src=defaultImg;
            prevIndex = index;
            this.src=imgs[index];
        };
    })(i));
  };

})();
```

Comment: I don't know what you did there...I'm new to all this programming stuff. I'm trying to have it where if the user clicks the graphic button A, it changes to another version of that graphic in an active state. But if button B were clicked then button A gets reverted back, while B is changed. I'm guessing this would have to be an "if else" statement. I just don't know how to go about it.

Comment: I used two flags to record the previous and current selection index of img. Previous img will be converted to origin picture when user clicked another picture (pokers[prevIndex].src=defaultImg;). Then change the current selected img to another version picture (this.src=imgs[index]).